# Probelms downloading and opening packaging, lib not specified

Tags: installation, library-path

I am using R 4.2.3 and try to install packages but have problems now. The following appears when trying to install OpenMX:

> install.packages("OpenMx")
> Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
> install.packages("OpenMx")
> Installiere Paket nach ‘C:/Users/jsart/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
> (da ‘lib’ nicht spezifiziert)
> trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/OpenMx_2.21.1.zip'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 8655881 bytes (8.3 MB)
> downloaded 8.3 MB

Paket ‘OpenMx’ erfolgreich ausgepackt und MD5 Summen abgeglichen
Warning in install.packages :
kann alte Installation von Paket ‘OpenMx’ nicht entfernen
Warning in install.packages :
problem copying C:\Users\jsart\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\00LOCK\OpenMx\libs\x64\OpenMx.dll to C:\Users\jsart\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\OpenMx\libs\x64\OpenMx.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
‘OpenMx’ wiederhergestellt

Die heruntergeladenen Binärpakete sind in
C:\Users\jsart\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgXGBFT\downloaded_packages

What is wrong with the library path? It seems like the packages have problems being installed and thus I cannot open the libraries since R tells me they are not existent:

> library(OpenMx)
> Error in library(OpenMx) : es gibt kein Paket namens ‘OpenMx’

I tried adjusting the library path, R shows me two paths:

> .libPaths()
> [1] "C:/Users/jsart/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2"
> [2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.3/library"